# Eclipse DTP is not creating a connection

Tags: eclipse, database-connection

I am using MariaDB and am currently trying to create a database connection using DTP.

When I test the connection the ping is succeeding:

[image: succeeding]

When I click on 'Finish' afterwards, the 'Database Connections' Folder is still empty:

[image: empty :(]

Am I missing a step or am I encountering a bug?

working with Eclipse Neo.3 on Arch Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was rather simple: uninstall DTP and install DBeaver.

I didnt knew that DTP was outdated and got more or less abandoned by his community.